# How do i do a clean install of mamp pro 3 (windows)

Tags: windows, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm using mamp pro 3 windows version, can anyone tell me if it's possible to do a clean install. The recommended uninstall via windows isn't a total uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To completly unistall MAMP and MAMP PRO first do uninstall procedure. Afterwards go to Windows Explorer. If you have installed MAMP in folder 'C:\MAMP' delete complete folders 'C:\MAMP' and 'C:\MAMPPRO'. If you have installed it at another place change directories accordingly. After removing folders go to your Users folder and delete MAMPRO folder from:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\

and delete MAMPPRO folder from:

C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming\Appsolute\

Change [yourusername] to your actual username.

That will completely delete all MAMP and MAMP PRO folders.